# How to redirect permanently the "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" in outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to know how to redirect permanently the "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" in outlook 2007.

I have already tested to make different rules and spam redirect but, the undelivered mails continues to come in my inbox.

Do outlook have a special configuration, does someone knows why i cant redirect my undelivered mails ?

Please test it **YOURSELF** and you will know it is not simple as making a rule with the message or the sender name...

Comment: How are you attempting to redirect the undeliverable messages?  What does your rule state?

Comment: Test it yourserlf and you will see you cant redirect server error mails after making a rule.
For exemple i redirect mails "FROM" "Mail Delivery Subsystem" by clicking left on the mail and create a rule, that works for the mails already in the mailbox, but the next mails dont use the rule.
I know how to make rules it is not a mistake, it is a real question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with your saved "nk2" of that user. 
Attempt this resolution first:
Open a new message, start typing there email address, when there name shows up in a drop down list..click delete, now manually type in there email address once. Let me know id this works. Also please attach the contents of the bounced back message, for further troubleshooting, if needed. 
:) good luck, Willy

Comment: Please *don't* use signatures or taglines in your posts.